# How to add circular progress bar on Future Builder with out screen freeze

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flashcards_quiz/models/model.dart';
import 'package:flashcards_quiz/util/theme.dart';
import 'package:flashcards_quiz/views/flashcard_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late int level;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadsts();
  }

  _loadsts() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var newlevel = prefs.getInt('level') ?? 1;
    setState(() {
      level = newlevel;
    });
    // print(level);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: ListView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'List',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              const Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                  future: getDataLocally(context),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                          child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                            strokeWidth: 4.0,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "Loading ... ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                          // Use any loader widget you prefer
                          );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      // Handle errors
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      final data = snapshot.data;
                      return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          childAspectRatio: 0.85,
                        ),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final topicsData = data[index];
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (level >= index + 1) {
                               
                                 Navigator.push(
                               context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => NewCard(
                                    level: index + 1,
                                     questions: topicsData.questions,
                                 name: topicsData.name,
                                   ),
                                  ),
                               );
                              } else {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content:
                                      Text('Please Complete  Level $level'),
                                ));
                              }
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              color: level >= index + 1 ? unlockedBg : lockedBg,
                              elevation: 10,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      level >= index + 1 ? unlocked : locked,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 55,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 15,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Level  ${index + 1}',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .headlineSmall!
                                          .copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Quiz>> getDataLocally(BuildContext context) async {
  final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
  final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  final reportData = quizFromJson(data);
  return reportData;
}
```

Issues

- i have placed a circular progress bar on future builder but it's freeze when we open the app. so i remove it. i used every type of animation but it's not working .
- when user complete quiz new level will be unlocked. the new level will be stored on local storage every time the use complete the quiz. when the user come back to the home page i want to check the current level from local storage and update the grid. currently it's not working when we come back to the page so i used like

```
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
                  );
```

this time the home page reload but for a view seconds until the list load the card page is freezing on screen

i want to place circular progress bar untile the json load

i want to refresh the grid with out freeze

Comment: You may create a state variable of `late final future  = getDataLocally(context),` and use this on FutureBuilder to avoid unnecessary API calls.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Still circular progress bar is stuck on screen

Comment: What  happens if you use a dummy future in place of `getDataLocally`

Comment: not working ----

Answer (score -1):

The question is not entirely clear, but if I have a long-running code that slows down the interface, then I wrap this code like this

```
await Future(() {
     //long-running code place 
});
```

try to use this approach in your code where most time is spent on calculations, for example

```
Future<List<Quiz>?> getDataLocally(BuildContext context) async {
  
 await Future(() {

         final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
         final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
         final reportData = quizFromJson(data);
         return reportData;

    });
}
```

Comment: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<List<Quiz>>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*

Comment: @dev.skas do you really know what you're doing? Made changes to my answer.

Comment: how i add await on another await

Comment: @dev.skas how you do it, I don't know. How I do it I wrote in my answer.

Comment: chek you answer there is two await how is it possible

Comment: @dev.skas  https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: can you please check you answer once more

Comment: @dev.skas  I don't have the complete code, with models and so on. What I wrote to you should work. You don't understand what it is `null safety` this was the problem, I fixed it, added a question mark in the return value `List<Quiz>?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255146/discussion-between-dev-skas-and--).